# How would I go about freeing this malloc in order to prevent any memory leaks when using valgrind

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, singly-linked-list

How and where would I put a free() function in this piece of code in order to prevent memory leaks when I valgrind. (This is just a piece of a larger code)

```c
pizzaNode * AddTopping1 (char *s, pizzaNode * head) {

    pizzaNode * newPtr = (pizzaNode *)(malloc(sizeof(pizzaNode)));
    
    // set values of the new node
    strcpy(newPtr->topping, s);
    newPtr->next = NULL;
    
    // Add the topping to the beginning of the list:
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        newPtr->next = head;
        //head = newPtr;
    }

    
    return newPtr;  // newPtr is the new head now
}
```

Or at least what is the syntax to write a free() function for this malloc?

Comment: There shouldn't be any `free` in the shown function. You should free the memory when you remove a node or free the whole list.

Comment: "*what is the syntax to write a free() function for this malloc*". What do you mean by that? To free the pointer it would be `free(newPtr);`. Is that really what you are asking? When and where that needs to be called depends on the rest of your code - which you have not shown and hence we cannot say for sure. Please provide a complete [mre] if you want further help.

Comment: Unrelated. the if-else is pointless, especially considering `head = ` means nothing to the caller of this function. Just do `newPtr->next = head; return newPtr;`. This function is synonymous with a "push-front" action, assuming the caller is doing `head = AddTopping1(...., head);`

Answer (score 2):

It seems this function adds a new node to a list.

The dynamically allocated memory for the list should be freed when the list is not needed any more as for example

```
void clear( pizzaNode **head )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        pizzaNode *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );  
    }
}
```

If in the caller you declared a pointer to the head node like for example

```
pizzaNode *head = NULL;
```

then the function is called like

```
clear( &head );
```